# Find the value of $\delta> 0$ for….

Tags: calculus

The question is:

sketch the interval $({1\over4},{1\over2})$ on the $x$ axis with the point $x_0= {2\over5}$ inside. Then find a value of $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$, $0 < | x-x_0 | < \delta$ implies ${1\over4} < x < {1\over2}$.

If someone could tell me how to start this question it would be greatly appreciated! Not looking for the answer just the steps to work through it.

Comment: I posted an answer, but I think I should point out that you need to realize that $|x-x_0|$ is just the distance between $x$ and $x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** How far away from 2/5 can $x$ be, if it is not as far away as $1/4$ is or $1/2$ is? It can't be as far away as either of those is. So how close to 2/5 is the closest of 1/4 and 1/2? To answer this, you must first answer: how close to 2/5 is 1/4? And how close to 2/5 is 1/2? Then: which is closer?

Answer (score 0):

Check that $|\frac{1}{4}-\frac{2}{5}|=0.15$ and $|\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{5}|=0.10$, then you've got to take $\delta<0.10$.